# JavaScript Performance and Memory Access

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, v8, rhino

**EDIT**

Did a JSPerf. Ran it against Chrome as Chrome uses v8.

http://jsperf.com/passing-large-objects

It looks like passing a large object doesn't matter; the difference is negligible. However, lookup on an object at some point gets a lot slower.

**INTRODUCTION:**

I’m writing a 2D JavaScript game engine while following component based and data oriented (via typed arrays) design principles. It’s designed for use by a simulation based multiplayer netcode.

My performance concerns are for the master simulation that will be running on the server; I believe that client browsers will be more than fast enough. As of now, the server is NodeJS, so it would involve the V8 interpreter. However, I’m not ruling out a switch to other technologies like Vert.x, which I believe uses the Rhino interpreter.

**THE QUESTION:**

When does JavaScript access objects in memory?

More specifically, let’s say I have an object like so.

```
var data = {
    a1 : new Float64Array(123456),
    a2 : new Float64Array(123456),
    …
    a9001: new Float64Array(123456)
};
```

And now let’s say I pass it to this function like so.

```
var update = function(obj) {
    for(var property in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            obj[property][0]++;
        }
    }
};
update(data);
```

At what point are the Float64 arrays accessed? Does it access it the moment I pass data into update, attempting to load all 9001 arrays into the memory cache and page faulting like crazy? Does it wait to load the arrays until the hasOwnProperty? Or obj[property]? Or obj[property][0]?

**WHY I ASK:**

I’m trying to follow the data oriented design principles of keeping stuff in contiguous blocks of memory. Depending on how JavaScript works with memory, I will have to change the interface and structure of the engine.

For example, if all the arrays in data are accessed the moment I pass it into update, then I have to make special data objects with as few arrays as possible to reduce page faulting. If however the arrays are only accessed at say obj[property], then I can pass a large data object with more arrays without any performance penalties, which simplifies a lot of things.

A big reason why I’m not sure of the answer is because JavaScript objects aren’t objects like in other languages. From some random reading here or there, I’ve heard stuff like JavaScript objects have their own internal class. I’ve also heard of things like JavaScript objects being hash tables so you incur a lookup time with every property that you access.

Then I’ve heard that the interpreters treat objects differently based on how large the object is; smaller ones are treated one way and larger ones another. So jsperf stuff may not be an accurate measure.

**FURTHER:**

Taking the example further, there’s the question of how JavaScript handles nested objects. For example:

```
var properties = {
    a1 : {
        a1 : {
            …
            a1 : {
            }
        }
    },
    a2 : {
        a2 : {
            …
            a2 : {
            }
        }
    },
    …
    a9001 : {
        a9001 : {
            …
            a9001 : {
            }
        }
    }
};
var doSomething = function() {
};
doSomething(properties);
```

If passing in properties to doSomething causes every sub object and their sub objects to get accessed, then that’s a performance hit. If however it just passes a reference to the properties object and only accesses the sub objects when the code calls them, then it’s not bad at all.

If I had access to Vectors, I’d make an entity system framework in a heartbeat and this wouldn’t really be a problem. If I had access to pointers, which I believe only accesses the object when the code converts the pointer, then I could try other things. But only having typed arrays at my disposal limits my options, so I end up agonizing over questions like this.

Thanks for the any insight you can provide. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I would bet that each `Float64Array` is not *part of* the `data` object/HashTable/whatever, but only referenced from there. However, to get a definitive answer you probably will need to look at the V8 code.

Comment: In my limited experience, It seems to me that it just passes a reference. Which is pretty much true for all languages. (Although, passing strings, however, is different in places.) I've wrote code in JavaScript that generated huge objects with further impeded objects. Passing them to functions over and over never seemed to be an issue nor optimize-able. I would think you could easily write benchmarking code to test.

Comment: Furthermore, I would assume that in all implementations. If you pass an object [reference] to a function. And in that function you change a member of the object to a new value. You will not need to return this object, references outside the function will see the change in this object they are referring to. Thus, its always passing a reference, not making a local copy for this function (which would be the only reason I could think of that the interpreter would want to access all child objects of a function parameter). Then again, I could have my head in the clouds, thats my two cents.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit: There never will be created local copies when calling functions, as objects are reference values. OP does want to *how large the memory needed for the `data` object is when iterating its properties* - basically the internal memory management of V8.

Comment: Ya, thats what I was hinting at. But, I was assuming that because they are passed in by reference, then the function doesn't go and access (touch) each child just when the function is called (why would it? unless it was trying to make a copy). As in the OPs question "Does it access it the moment I pass data into update, attempting to load all 9001 arrays into the memory cache and page faulting like crazy?" I was assuming to be no. But as we all know: Assumption is the mother of all epic fails.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! http://jsperf.com/passing-large-objects It looks like passing a large object doesn't matter; the difference is negligible. However, lookup on an object at some point gets a lot slower. Hmm.

Comment: Your `accessTest` is a no-op and could be completely optimized away. I've edited in a property access, and also created the `Float64Array`s of different sizes in http://jsperf.com/passing-large-objects/2

Comment: Strictly speaking `accessTest` in your code is also no-op and can be optimized away. There are two main problems with the test: cross polution with polymorphic type feedback and forcing objects into slow dictionary mode due to too much properties. http://jsperf.com/passing-large-objects/3 tries to address both.

Comment: Ooh. I asked about one thing and ended up learning a lot of other things about JavaScript. Very cool. The making an object via a constructor speeding it up is of particular interest to me; I didn't realize the difference would be that much. I guess it's because V8 creates an internal class if all the properties are set in the constructor rather than using a hash table. I assume that it is the same for object literals, where it's fast as long as you don't modify the object properties after it was created initially? Thanks for the help so far; it's been very beneficial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when does javascript initialize vars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260375/when-does-javascript-initialize-vars)