# when does javascript initialize vars?

Tags: javascript, initialization

```
var x = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", ...];
function f() {
  var y = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", ...];
}
```

It is a big array, at least in my opinion.

I assume `y` gets initialized again at every instance.

Would a global `x` be initialized only one time when page is loaded?   Seems reasonable...

Comment: In my experience, most likely.. Yes.

Comment: It's not about the variable. Your problem is that another *array* is created every time the literal is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

yes (+27 chars to satisfy SO!)

Comment: I'm sorry to say y'all are talking over my level.  :)   I don't know about 27 chars?  This array is about 1400 chars.   And I don't understand about another array created at every evaluation?

Comment: @WayneF SO has a minimum character limit on answers (and comments). Another array is created during each function call because you're creating an array inside the function.